# Okular opens large pdfs with blank pages

Tags: kubuntu, pdf, okular, ebooks

I can't open large files (above 10MB) with Okular. This is a problem with files I save and open up in Dolphin and files I open directly in Firefox (i.e.e-books).

Symptoms:
-PDF opens but is blank or PDF opens but most pages are blank. 
-CPU starts working way too hard
-Problem continues regardless of how I save file

The contents of PDF file show when I import it into my reference manager Mendeley (or on other OS).

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Mendeley has limited space.

I just updated KDE desktop to 4.12 as this was suggested somewhere, and it made no difference.

Thanks! Kubuntu newbee

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename the file and then reopen it again. For me it happened when i tried to highlight a line, the whole file suddenly turned blank white. I renamed the file and reopened it and it displayed the pages normally again, but unfortunately without the highlighting... i don't think that Okular can handle such large files, mine was 90MBs